# Отследить закрытие контекстного меню

Tags: android, java

У `activity` для работы с контекстным меню переопределены методы

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info)
```

и

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

В них создается меню и обрабатывается клик. А как отследить закрытие контекстного меню? Ведь оно закрывается не только тогда, когда пользователь выбрал пункт меню, но и при отмене (закрытие меню без выбора `MenuItem`).

Подобный метод есть для `OptionsMenu`:

```
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)
```

а для контекстного меню такого метода нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Внимательно" Вы доку читаете:
onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu)
[Дока](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Я просто работаю с `Fragment`, а не с `Activity`. Странно, что во фрагменте нельзя обработать скрытие контекстного меню.

Comment: Понятно почему. Фрагмент это всего лишь повторяющиеся куски разметки(если я правильно понял, ибо попробовать на практике все никак не могу, проекты да проекты писать приходится), а активити - есть активити.
P.s. В вопросе была написана активити:)